# Facebook PHP SDK - getLoginUrl() and getLogoutUrl() not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, logout

This is driving me insane, I can't figure out why this simple page would have problems letting me login and logout of my app?

The Error I get is:

> OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

```php
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
include_once( 'fb-sdk/src/facebook.php');
$appid = '****';
$appsecret = '****';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appid,
  'secret' => $appsecret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

try{
 $user = $facebook->api('/me');
 echo '<h1>HELLO '.$user['full_name'].'</h1>';
}catch(Exception $e){

    echo $e; 
}

    echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl .'">logout</a> ';

    echo '<a href="'.$loginUrl .'">login</a> ';
?>
```

Comment: does the login url show properly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the permissions

```
$params = array(
'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: Parameters are optional, don't have to have them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `echo $e;` from your code and it shouldn't display the message.

Comment: It does display the error with echo $e: OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Comment: Doesn't it mean when you cannot get the $user that the user is already logged out and you need to give them the login button?

Comment: It will remove the message, but doesn't make the error go away

Comment: I thought your issue was there was a an error displayed to the user along with the login/logout buttons?  Do the buttons not show up?  Do the buttons fail to work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at http://samoldak.com/index.php/fixing-facebooks-php-sdk-logout/

You need to create a separate logout page and kill the Facebook session associated with your domain manually.